# From user tag to user id

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm tryng to create a funcion that gives me the id of the person who invited a new user based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7OUnSlDWEM , but this gives me the tag of the user (exemple: "username#0000")

```
module.exports = (client) => {

  const invites = {}

  const getInviteCounts = async (guild) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      guild.fetchInvites().then((invites) => {
        const inviteCounter = {}

        invites.forEach((invite) => {
          const { uses, inviter } = invite
          const { username, discriminator } = inviter
          const name = `${username}#${discriminator}`

          inviteCounter[name] = (inviteCounter[name] || 0) + uses
        })

        resolve(inviteCounter)
      })
    })
  }

  client.guilds.cache.forEach(async (guild) => {
    invites[guild.id] = await getInviteCounts(guild)
  })

  module.exports = {
      getInviter: async function getInviter(member){
          const { guild, id } = member
          const invitesBefore = invites[guild.id]
          const invitesAfter = await getInviteCounts(guild)       
          for (const inviter in invitesAfter) {
              if (invitesBefore[inviter] === invitesAfter[inviter] - 1) {
                  invites[guild.id] = invitesAfter
                  let result = member.guild.members.cache.find(c => c.tag === inviter)
                  return result
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I put `let result = member.guild.members.cache.find(c => c.tag === inviter)` to get the user objet from that tag to later I can use result.id but console.log(result) gives me undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `inviter` extension of [Invite](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Invite?scrollTo=inviter) provides you with the User object of said user, hence why your only task left is to get his ID using

```
const { inviter } = invite
console.log(inviter.id)
```